# Change FROM part of a query depending on column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named tasks with a columns named task_type, task_group and keyid. Then there is another table named task_groups with two columns: keyid and name.

If a task has a task_type equal to 2 then I know that task_group contains the keyid value for the entry in table task_groups that contains the name of the task. If task_type is any other value then task_group is -1. So what i want is to write a query that returns the task type always AND the name of the task_group  but only if task_type is 2, all of this for a given task.

For this I use a script with the following logic (3 is a tasks.keyid example):

```
SELECT task_type,task_group AS tgid FROM tasks WHERE keyid = 3;
if (task_type == 2)
    SELECT name FROM task_group WHERE keyid = tgid
```

Is there a way to write one query to do this?

EDIT: Adding some sample data

```
Table task:
+++ keyid +++ task_group +++ task_type
+++ 25    +++ -2         +++ 0
+++ 26    +++ -2         +++ 1
+++ 27    +++ 132        +++ 2
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Table task_groups:
+++ keyid +++ name          
+++ 132   +++ a task group
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Expected output when replacing the value 3 in the above code would be

```
(tasks.keyid = 25) task_type = 0, task_group_name = ""
(tasks.keyid = 26) task_type = 1, task_group_name = ""
(tasks.keyid = 27) task_type = 2, task_group_name = "a task group"
```

I hope this is good enough.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected result or make a fiddle.

Comment: At Ullas. I hope that was usefull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    t.task_type, t.task_group AS tgid,
    IF (t.task_type = 2, g.name, '') AS group_name
FROM tasks t
LEFT JOIN task_group g ON t.task_group = g.keyid
WHERE t.keyid = 3
;
```

this query should return group name if type = 2 or empty string otherwise.

Comment: I got a syntax error. This is the copy and pasted query I wrote. I see no difference with yours: SELECT t.task_type, t.task_group AS tgid, IF (t.task_type = 2, g.name, '') AS group_name FROM tasks t WHERE t.keyid = 190 LEFT JOIN task_groups g ON t.task_group = g.keyid

Comment: Oops... i put where condition it wrong place... already fixed